# Eclipse - Git - Can't pull/push from a repository url with caret (^) sign

Tags: eclipse, git, illegal-characters

Did someone encounter this problem with eclipse?
I keep getting the error "cannot open git-upload-pack" when opening the error log, I see this is caused by an illegal character '^'.
I can't change the git repository location.
When executing "git pull" from command line, it works fine.
(I am using eclipse neon version)

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the caret with it's equivalent URI code:`%5E`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work... It automatically switches the code to ^ on save.